# How to run ACCESS with multiple users in optimistic mode

Tags: ms-access, multi-user

I wonder how to set up MS ACCESS to run in multi-user mode with optimistic record locking.  Presently, it is installed on two PCs and the DB files sit on a server.  When the second user tries to go into ACCESS, he just hangs until the other guy exits ACCESS.  Then his terminal goes in and he can see the files.

Any tips would be appreciated...

DKoss

Answer (score 1):

The general suggested approach here is to split the database, and then place the front end (application part) on each PC. How to do this is outlined here:

http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/split/index.htm

The locking issue(s) are separate from above. Your existing setup should in fact work, but likely the users don’t have enough permissions to that folder. EACH user requires create and delete rights to the folder since on startup Access creates a locking file in that folder – if such locking files cannot be created then the application is opened in single user mode. So you don’t have to split, but as the above article notes, it is a good idea.

Note that EVEN if you split the database, you STILL encounter your problem and issue until such time you give users create and delete rights to that folder. Without such rights then Access will operate in single user mode as you describe.